# How to create frames inside Tkinter windows

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, widget, frames

I am trying to create frames inside tkinter windows so that I can create label and entry widgets inside the frames but I am not succeeding. I am actually trying to develop a management system. Kindly, can someone help me edit the codes below to create the frames inside the "Schain" and "HR" windows? I will appreciate it.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.constants import *

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1200x900")
root.title("Hospital Management System")

schain_active = False
hr_active = False
root_active = True


# menus for the HR DPT
class HRWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.add_menus()
        self.add_content()

    def add_menus(self):
        # menus for the HR DPT

        menubar = tk.Menu(self)

        File = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        File.add_command(label='Open File')
        File.add_command(label='Save')
        File.add_command(label='Exit')
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=File)

        Departments = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        Departments.add_command(label='Human Resource Department',command=HR_change)
        Departments.add_command(label='Supply chain Department',command=Schain_change)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Departments", menu=Departments)

        Help = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        Help.add_command(label='About ihms')
        Help.add_command(label='Manual')
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=Help)

        Settings = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        Settings.add_command(label='Log Out')
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Settings", menu=Settings)

        #configure menu for root
        self.config(menu=menubar)
    
    def add_content(self):
        # content in self window pages

        HRmainframe=tk.Frame(HR, width=900, height=800, bd=1, padx=20, pady=20, bg=”red”, relief=RIDGE)
HRmainframe.grid()

        Email = tk.Label(HRmainframe, text="Email")
        Email.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=2, sticky=W)
        Emailentry = tk.Entry(HRmainframe, width=40)
        Emailentry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=20)

class SchainWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.add_content()
    
    def add_content(self):
schainmainframe=tk.Frame(Schain, width=900, height=800, bd=1, padx=20, pady=20, bg=”blue”, relief=RIDGE)
schainmainframe.grid()

        name = tk.Label(schainmainframe, text="Name")
        name.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=2, sticky=W)
        nameentry = tk.Entry(schainmainframe, width=40)
        nameentry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=20)



def HR_change():
    global HR, schain_active, hr_active, root_active

    HR = HRWindow()
    HR.geometry("1200x900")
    HR.title("HR")
    hr_active = True

    if root_active:
        root.destroy()
        root_active = False
    
    if schain_active:
        Schain.destroy()
        schain_active = False

def Schain_change():
    global Schain, hr_active, schain_active, root_active

    Schain = SchainWindow()
    Schain.geometry("1200x900")
    Schain.title("SUPPLY CHAIN")
    schain_active = True
    
    if root_active:
        root.destroy()
        root_active = False

    if hr_active:
        HR.destroy()
        hr_active = False

# menus for the root
menubar = tk.Menu(root)

File  = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
File.add_command(label='Open File')
File.add_command(label='Save')
File.add_command(label='Exit')
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=File)

Departments = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
Departments.add_command(label='Human Resource Department',command=HR_change)
Departments.add_command(label='Supply chain Department',command=Schain_change)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Departments", menu=Departments)

Help = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
Help.add_command(label='About ihms')
Help.add_command(label='Manual')
menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=Help)

Settings = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
Settings.add_command(label='Log Out')
menubar.add_cascade(label="Settings", menu=Settings)

#configure menu for root
root.config(menu=menubar)


# content in root window pages
name = tk.Label(root, text="Name")
name.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=2, sticky=W)
nameentry = tk.Entry(root, width=40)
nameentry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=20)

Age = tk.Label(root, text="Age")
Age.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=20, sticky=W)
Ageentry = tk.Entry(root, width=40)
Ageentry.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=20)

# destroy the program
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your children windows should inherit from `tk.Toplevel` rather than `tk.Tk`. They should also use `self` when you try to create frames inside them e.g. `self.HRmainframe=tk.Frame(self)`

Comment: Hi, Scotty3785, thank you for your response. I have tried it but I am wondering why the label and Entry widgets inside the "HR," and "Schain" windows are not displayed. Would you please paste the edited code?

Comment: What does "I am not succeeding" mean? What is it doing, and how is that different from what you expect?

Comment: This code has some indentation issues, can you please try to fix them?

Answer (score 0):

There are some other issues with the code that I haven't resolved below but this does resolve the original issue of frames not being shown in the children windows.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.constants import *

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1200x900")
root.title("Hospital Management System")

schain_active = False
hr_active = False
root_active = True


# menus for the HR DPT
class HRWindow(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.add_menus()
        self.add_content()

    def add_menus(self):
        # menus for the HR DPT

        menubar = tk.Menu(self)

        File = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        File.add_command(label='Open File')
        File.add_command(label='Save')
        File.add_command(label='Exit')
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=File)

        Departments = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        Departments.add_command(label='Human Resource Department',command=HR_change)
        Departments.add_command(label='Supply chain Department',command=Schain_change)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Departments", menu=Departments)

        Help = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        Help.add_command(label='About ihms')
        Help.add_command(label='Manual')
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=Help)

        Settings = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        Settings.add_command(label='Log Out')
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Settings", menu=Settings)

        #configure menu for root
        self.config(menu=menubar)
    
    def add_content(self):
        # content in self window pages

        HRmainframe=tk.Frame(self, width=900, height=800, bd=1, padx=20, pady=20, bg="red", relief=RIDGE)
        HRmainframe.grid()

        Email = tk.Label(HRmainframe, text="Email")
        Email.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=2, sticky=W)
        Emailentry = tk.Entry(HRmainframe, width=40)
        Emailentry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=20)

class SchainWindow(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.add_content()
    
    def add_content(self):
        schainmainframe=tk.Frame(self, width=900, height=800, bd=1, padx=20, pady=20, bg="blue", relief=RIDGE)
        schainmainframe.grid()

        name = tk.Label(schainmainframe, text="Name")
        name.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=2, sticky=W)
        nameentry = tk.Entry(schainmainframe, width=40)
        nameentry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=20)



def HR_change():
    global HR, schain_active, hr_active, root_active

    HR = HRWindow()
    HR.geometry("1200x900")
    HR.title("HR")
    hr_active = True

def Schain_change():
    global Schain, hr_active, schain_active, root_active

    Schain = SchainWindow()
    Schain.geometry("1200x900")
    Schain.title("SUPPLY CHAIN")
    schain_active = True

# menus for the root
menubar = tk.Menu(root)

File  = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
File.add_command(label='Open File')
File.add_command(label='Save')
File.add_command(label='Exit')
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=File)

Departments = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
Departments.add_command(label='Human Resource Department',command=HR_change)
Departments.add_command(label='Supply chain Department',command=Schain_change)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Departments", menu=Departments)

Help = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
Help.add_command(label='About ihms')
Help.add_command(label='Manual')
menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=Help)

Settings = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
Settings.add_command(label='Log Out')
menubar.add_cascade(label="Settings", menu=Settings)

#configure menu for root
root.config(menu=menubar)


# content in root window pages
name = tk.Label(root, text="Name")
name.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=2, sticky=W)
nameentry = tk.Entry(root, width=40)
nameentry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=20)

Age = tk.Label(root, text="Age")
Age.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=20, sticky=W)
Ageentry = tk.Entry(root, width=40)
Ageentry.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=20)

# destroy the program
root.mainloop()
```

I've removed the sections of code that destroy the root window since an application should always have one and only one `Tk` instance.

Comment: Hi Scotty3785, thank you. I have tried your recommended code but it is giving me the background color for the frames hanging only on the top-left and not covering the whole window as I desired. Also, when the other sections of the code are removed, a window will always open and the previous existing window will not be destroyed. I only wanted a single window to be active at a time and not several windows. Kindly guide.

Comment: Your original question asked about creating frames. StackOverflow questions help with specific questions rather than being a "Code Doctor" service where all of your problems are fixed. If you have more questions on your project, raise a new question.

Comment: Hi  Scotty3785, sorry if this did not come out well. I was only trying to justify why I had the other sections which you removed.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a class that inherits from a widget and you want to put frames inside that object, you need to place them in `self`.

Instead of this:

```
def add_content(self):
    schainmainframe=tk.Frame(Schain, ...)
    ...
```

It needs to be this:

```
def add_content(self):
    schainmainframe=tk.Frame(self, ...)
    ...
```

You need to make a similar change in the other `add_content` method.

You also have two root windows which is not how tkinter is designed to be used. Unless you have a fairly deep understanding of tkinter, you should only have a single instance of `Tk`. I don't know if that's contributing to your problem, but it will certainly cause behavior that you don't expect.